# Why React does not update and re-render the component when clicked on buttons?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, codepen

Here I use embed codepen library for react. When I click the buttons I want to change the active codepen component showing on the `{activeCodePen}`. But when I do console.log the `activeCodePen` I notice that it changes but rendered component on the screen does not change. How can I fix this?

I tried both `setActiveCodePen(() => renderCodePen(1))` or `setActiveCodePen(renderCodePen(1))`

```
const PageNotFound: React.FC = () => {

  function renderCodePen(index: number){
    switch (index) {
      case 1:
        return <ReactCodepen user="MichaelKhalifar" hash="JjZYENK" height={700}  loader={() => <div>Loading...</div>} themeId="31205" /> 
      case 2:
        return <ReactCodepen user="saifkeralite" hash="GRGyKEz" height={700}  loader={() => <div>Loading...</div>} themeId="31205" /> 
      case 3:
        return <ReactCodepen user="saifkeralite" hash="yLBQaaY" height={700}  loader={() => <div>Loading...</div>} themeId="31205" /> 
      default:
        return <ReactCodepen user="saifkeralite" hash="yLBQaaY" height={700}  loader={() => <div>Loading...</div>} themeId="31205" />
    }
  }

  const [activeCodePen, setActiveCodePen] = useState(renderCodePen(1));

  return (
    <div className={styles.mainContainer}>
      {activeCodePen}
      <button onClick={() => {setActiveCodePen(() => renderCodePen(1))}}>1</button>
      <button onClick={() => {setActiveCodePen(() => renderCodePen(2))}}>2</button>
      <button onClick={() => {setActiveCodePen(() => renderCodePen(3))}}>3</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to not store whole component in state, but instead store only index:

```
const PageNotFound: React.FC = () => {

  function renderCodePen(index: number){
    switch (index) {
      case 1:
        return <ReactCodepen user="MichaelKhalifar" hash="JjZYENK" height={700}  loader={() => <div>Loading...</div>} themeId="31205" /> 
      case 2:
        return <ReactCodepen user="saifkeralite" hash="GRGyKEz" height={700}  loader={() => <div>Loading...</div>} themeId="31205" /> 
      case 3:
        return <ReactCodepen user="saifkeralite" hash="yLBQaaY" height={700}  loader={() => <div>Loading...</div>} themeId="31205" /> 
      default:
        return <ReactCodepen user="saifkeralite" hash="yLBQaaY" height={700}  loader={() => <div>Loading...</div>} themeId="31205" />
    }
  }

  const [activeCodePen, setActiveCodePen] = useState(1);

  return (
    <div className={styles.mainContainer}>
      {renderCodePen(activeCodePen)}
      <button onClick={() => {setActiveCodePen(1)}}>1</button>
      <button onClick={() => {setActiveCodePen(2)}}>2</button>
      <button onClick={() => {setActiveCodePen(3)}}>3</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I am not really sure why your solution dont work, it may be caused because your ReactCodepen components have the same "key" so react dont know that something changed.

Try this solution, it should work

Comment: well I tried and also put `<p>{activeCodePen}</p>` to display the number on the screen. But when I click the buttons number changes but `<ReactCodePen />` does not change.

Comment: then try to set "key={index}" in reactCodepen components if it helps